# Error detection before code execution starts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, handler, detection

Is it possible to detect errors before the code starts to run?
I have a Discord bot, and I would like the command handler that prints all loaded commands to the console to show the status for errors in advance.
Command handler at the moment:

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const ascii = require("ascii-table");
const list = new ascii('Commands');
list.setHeading('Command', 'Loaded');
module.exports = (bot) => {
    let commands = readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
    for (let file of commands) {
        let command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        if (command.name) {
            bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
            list.addRow(file, '✅');
        } else {
            list.addRow(file, '❌');
            continue;
        }
    }
    console.log(list.toString());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "detect errors"?

Comment: @Baker Sometimes I make mistakes in commands and don't notice them. When the commands are loaded, the application does not crash immediately, as if these errors do not exist. I become aware of the error only when I start executing a certain command.

Comment: This is not possible. Javascript is not a compiled language (often just-in-time compiled) so the code is running as it is. Some of the simple spelling errors can be found by using Typescript. What you can do to prevent the bot from failing is to wrap commands in `try catch` blocks and then later disable the command if it has failed in a certain way or just simply send a message to the user that the command execution has failed. A good practice is to also write unit tests these can also catch some errors before shipping finished code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `try` and `catch` statements of Javascript. In this way, if an error occurs still it will not break your code or bot. It will continue running without any problem.

*If you don't want to show anything and want to continue running the bot:*

```js
try {
  const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
  const ascii = require("ascii-table");
  const list = new ascii("Commands");
  list.setHeading("Command", "Loaded");
  module.exports = (bot) => {
    let commands = readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter((file) =>
      file.endsWith(".js")
    );
    for (let file of commands) {
      let command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
      if (command.name) {
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
        list.addRow(file, "✅");
      } else {
        list.addRow(file, "❌");
        continue;
      }
    }
    console.log(list.toString());
  };
} catch (e) {
  // Don't do anything
}
```

*Incase you want to print out the error to the console and continue running the bot. Then you can add a `console.log()` under the catch statement:*

```js
try {
  const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
  const ascii = require("ascii-table");
  const list = new ascii("Commands");
  list.setHeading("Command", "Loaded");
  module.exports = (bot) => {
    let commands = readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter((file) =>
      file.endsWith(".js")
    );
    for (let file of commands) {
      let command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
      if (command.name) {
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
        list.addRow(file, "✅");
      } else {
        list.addRow(file, "❌");
        continue;
      }
    }
    console.log(list.toString());
  };
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```